# Subgroups of Weil-Deligne group

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $K$ be a $p$-adic field, i.e. a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. As I understand it, when studying Galois representations of $K$, in particualr $p$-adic ones, the "correct" thing to do is to study representations of the Weil-Deligne group $\text{WD}_K$. I'm wondering if there is a description of the closed subgroups of $\text{WD}_K$ in terms of certain field extensions of $K$ remeniscent of the bijection between closed subgroups of the absolute Galois group $G_K$ and Galois extensions of $K$?

Comment: $\sigma\in WD_K$ must act on the residue field of $\overline{K}$ as an integer power of the Frobenius. $H\to \overline{K}^H$ makes the closed subgroups correspond to the extensions of $K$ with either algebraically closed or finite residue field. No intermediate allowed as in $\Bbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^{2^\infty}-1})$